# Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am running a method in the background using delayed-job (collectiveideas fork)

The method I am running is shown below, which fetches the price of the isbn:

```
  def update_prices(isbn13)
   @amazon = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=#{isbn13}"))
   price = @amazon.search('span.listprice').first.text.gsub('$', '')

   book = Book.find_by_isbn13(isbn13)
   book.update_attribute(:amazon_us_price, price)
  end
  handle_asynchronously :update_prices
```

Now when I run this, the job is added to the database but encounters an error when running.
The error is quite large, but I think the gist of it comes from the first line:
Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck.

```
{Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck. Handler: "--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod 
object: &id005 !ruby/object:BooksController 
  _action_name: show
  _config: !omap []

  _env: &id001 
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
    PATH_INFO: /books/9780425160985
    QUERY_STRING: \"\"
    REMOTE_ADDR: 127.0.0.1
    REMOTE_HOST: localhost
    REQUEST_METHOD: GET
    REQUEST_URI: http://localhost:3000/books/9780425160985
    SCRIPT_NAME: \"\"
    SERVER_NAME: localhost
    SERVER_PORT: \"3000\"
    SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
    SERVER_SOFTWARE: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2010-08-18)
    HTTP_HOST: localhost:3000
    HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive
    HTTP_REFERER: http://localhost:3000/books/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&keywords=hornets+nest&commit=Search
    HTTP_ACCEPT: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
    HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.107 Safari/534.13
    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-US,en;q=0.8
    HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
    HTTP_COOKIE: _bookcloud_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlMTNkZWFlYTdiYjVjN2IzZDAyOTU1MDc1NTc1ZDJlZDBJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFrUHJoT0RlZmZoSzIrSVdFdFJNbGxMckxENEZnMTM1STZuQUJCdHJuak1BPQY7AEY%3D--c2b7958a5461253129b6d363e3d547bd44c83f9d
    rack.version: 
    - 1
    - 1
    rack.input: !ruby/object:StringIO {}

    rack.errors: !ruby/object:IO {}

    rack.multithread: false
    rack.multiprocess: false
    rack.run_once: false
    rack.url_scheme: http
    HTTP_VERSION: HTTP/1.1
    REQUEST_PATH: /
    action_dispatch.parameter_filter: 
    - :password
    action_dispatch.secret_token: ab805f7bf1e681785a2ac4813edc43678cbe855682bc7ca9dc5f2116fc892d8ca41466f9bc261ef4ae15ad83c1c38780780d2f6bfe9c00c14abd68542a535400
    action_dispatch.remote_ip: !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::RemoteIpGetter 
      check_ip_spoofing: true
      env: *id001
      trusted_proxies: !ruby/regexp /(^127\\.0\\.0\\.1$|^(10|172\\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|30|31)|192\\.168)\\.)/i
    rack.session: !map:ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore::SessionHash 
      session_id: 13deaea7bb5c7b3d02955075575d2ed0
      _csrf_token: kPrhODeffhK2+IWEtRMllLrLD4Fg135I6nABBtrnjMA=
    rack.session.options: !map:ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore::OptionsHash 
      :path: /
      :domain: 
      :expire_after: 
      :secure: false
      :httponly: true
      :id: 13deaea7bb5c7b3d02955075575d2ed0
    rack.request.cookie_string: _bookcloud_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlMTNkZWFlYTdiYjVjN2IzZDAyOTU1MDc1NTc1ZDJlZDBJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFrUHJoT0RlZmZoSzIrSVdFdFJNbGxMckxENEZnMTM1STZuQUJCdHJuak1BPQY7AEY%3D--c2b7958a5461253129b6d363e3d547bd44c83f9d
    rack.request.cookie_hash: 
      _bookcloud_session: BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlMTNkZWFlYTdiYjVjN2IzZDAyOTU1MDc1NTc1ZDJlZDBJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFrUHJoT0RlZmZoSzIrSVdFdFJNbGxMckxENEZnMTM1STZuQUJCdHJuak1BPQY7AEY=--c2b7958a5461253129b6d363e3d547bd44c83f9d
    action_dispatch.cookies: !map:ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar 
      _bookcloud_session: BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlMTNkZWFlYTdiYjVjN2IzZDAyOTU1MDc1NTc1ZDJlZDBJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFrUHJoT0RlZmZoSzIrSVdFdFJNbGxMckxENEZnMTM1STZuQUJCdHJuak1BPQY7AEY=--c2b7958a5461253129b6d363e3d547bd44c83f9d
    action_dispatch.request.unsigned_session_cookie: 
      session_id: 13deaea7bb5c7b3d02955075575d2ed0
      _csrf_token: kPrhODeffhK2+IWEtRMllLrLD4Fg135I6nABBtrnjMA=
    action_dispatch.request.path_parameters: 
      :controller: books
      :action: show
      :isbn13: \"9780425160985\"
    action_controller.instance: *id005
    action_dispatch.request.content_type: 
    action_dispatch.request.request_parameters: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}

    rack.request.query_string: \"\"
    rack.request.query_hash: {}

    action_dispatch.request.query_parameters: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}

    action_dispatch.request.parameters: &id002 !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
      controller: books
      action: show
      isbn13: \"9780425160985\"
    action_dispatch.request.formats: 
    - !ruby/object:Mime::Type 
      string: text/html
      symbol: :html
      synonyms: 
      - application/xhtml+xml
  _headers: 
    Content-Type: text/html
  _params: *id002
  _request: &id003 !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Request 
    env: *id001
    filtered_parameters: 
      controller: books
      action: show
      isbn13: \"9780425160985\"
    fullpath: /books/9780425160985
    method: GET
    request_method: GET
  _response: !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Response 
    blank: false
    block: 
    body: []

    cache_control: {}

    cookie: []

    etag: 
    header: {}

    length: 0
    request: *id003
    sending_file: false
    status: 200
    writer: !ruby/object:Proc {}

  _response_body: 
  _status: 200
  action_has_layout: true
  author: Patricia Daniels Cornwell
  book: !ruby/ActiveRecord:Book 
    attributes: 
      isbn13: \"9780425160985\"
      title: Hornet's Nest
      author: Patricia Daniels Cornwell
      price: 
      created_at: &id004 2011-03-03 10:41:27.757528 Z
      updated_at: *id004
      amazon_us_price: 
      id: 38
  lookup: !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Document 
    decorators: 
    errors: []

    node_cache: 
    - !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Element {}

    - !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Element {}

    - !ruby/object:Nokogiri::XML::Element {}

  lookup_context: !ruby/object:ActionView::LookupContext 
    details: 
      :handlers: 
      - :erb
      - :rjs
      - :builder
      - :rhtml
      - :rxml
      :formats: 
      - :html
      :locale: 
      - :en
      - :en
    details_key: 
    frozen_formats: false
    skip_default_locale: false
    view_paths: !seq:ActionView::PathSet 
      - !ruby/object:ActionView::FileSystemResolver 
        cached: {}

        caching: false
        path: /Users/nick/Dropbox/rails/bookcloud/app/views
  title: Hornet's Nest
  view_context_class: 
method_name: :update_prices_without_delay
args: 
- \"9780425160985\"
"
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:81:in `rescue in payload_object'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:79:in `payload_object'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in `invoke_job'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in `timeout'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `block in run'
/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in `run'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:177:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:104:in `block in work_off'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `times'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `work_off'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in `block in start'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `loop'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `start'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rorticket/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/nick/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Any idea what may be causing the error? I have never heard of Syck before.

Comment: Hi Nick, I was wondering if the answer below actually worked for you? I'm on the same boat and have wasted hours trying to figure out what's going on to no avail so any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: It does not work for me either, I have tried to require yaml with the  'Syck' engine in both boot.rb and application.rb but I am still experiencing the same error.

Comment: Guys, I am desperate here too. The answer has been marked as correct but it does not work. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the following lines of code in **boot.rb (config\boot.rb)**

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
```

Comment: This answer should not be marked as correct. It does not seem to be working. See other comments on the question too.

Answer (score 0):

For those that this didn't work for, like me, I've found include the `Psych` gem to handle YAML parsing fixed the issue. See: [Delayed_job: Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367228/delayed-job-job-failed-to-load-uninitialized-constant-sycksyck)