# Delayed_job: Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Here's the error:

```
>> Delayed::Job.find(:last).last_error
=> {Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck. Handler: \"--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod \\nobject: &id007 !ruby/object:TryController \\n  _action_name: create
```

but I have syck ext installed.

Usage:

```
def create_user(name,pass,time)
  puts "hello"
  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://www.example.net/buildtest.php?hao=#{name}&mi=#{pass}&da=#{time}"))
end

def create
   delay.create_user("nihao000oei9","1","1")
end
```

gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.4'

ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]

Rails 3.0.1

thanks.

Comment: what is ` Syck::Syck. Handler` is it a gem. Make sure you are including it in your builder or in your config.rb file. Not to mention you need to install the plugin/gem if unless it is something different.

Comment: I have never heard of Syck before.when i get the error i add `require 'syck'` to config.rb.but the error always.

Comment: What version(s) of Ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0] and Rails 3.0.1

Comment: I'm trying to use it to delay sending emails using the following code: `mail.delivery_method.delay.deliver!(mail)` and I'm getting exactly the same error...

Answer (score 1):

I found this as an issue when I upgraded from Rails 2 to 3 and deployed to the Heroku Cedar stack. It's an issue when `Delayed_Job` attempts to deserialise the handler from the Job queue item. By default it uses the `Syck` YAML parser.

Turns out `Syck` isn't available on the Heroku Cedar stack.

Including the `Psych` gem and redeploying fixed it for me and allow me to re-invoke the failed jobs.

```
gem 'psych'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and it turned out to be a syntax error in my just-modified database.yml.

It was using a bad reference for cucumber:

```
test: &test
  database: test

cucumber:
  <<: &base
```