# Heroku not sending Delayed Job emails through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I'm trying to send emails using delayed job from my Rails 3.2 app on Heroku when someone fills out a form. I've been able to get the emails to send successfully through delayed job on my local development machine. I can also get the emails to send using delayed job if I run them manually through the console on Heroku. However, when someone submits a form which triggers the email, it will not send.

Here's my mailer:

```
class ClaimMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@coatchex.com"

  def patron(claim)
    mail(:to => claim.email, :subject => I18n.t('mailers.claims.patron.subject'))
  end

  def coatchex(claim)
    @claim = claim
    mail(:to => 'claims@coatchex.com', :subject => I18n.t('mailers.claims.coatchex.subject'))
  end
end
```

Here's my controller:

```
class ClaimsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'basic'

  def new
    @claim = CoatChex::Forms::Claim.new
  end

  def create
    @claim = CoatChex::Forms::Claim.new(params[:claim])
    if @claim.valid?
      ClaimMailer.delay.coatchex(@claim)
      render :thank_you
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Like I mentioned, If I run the following command through the Heroku console it queues the email up in delayed job and sends it just fine:

```
@claim = ...
ClaimMailer.delay.coatchex(@claim)
```

However, whenever I send it through the form, it does not trigger.

If I'm quick enough I can run Delayed::Job.count in the Heroku console and see a value of 1 before the job executes when submitting through the form. So I know delayed job is getting it. If I look at the worker logs using

```
heroku logs -p worker -t
```

I can see the job process getting logged when executing it manually but not when it goes through the form.

There are no failed jobs in the database.

Anybody run into anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. A good starting point was the information at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job#debugging - specifically, running `Delayed::Job.last.last_error` on the Heroku console.

In my case, the error I was getting was `Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck`, which was fixed by adding `psych` to my gemfile. See [Delayed_job: Job failed to load: uninitialized constant Syck::Syck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367228/delayed-job-job-failed-to-load-uninitialized-constant-sycksyck) and http://effectif.com/ruby-on-rails/syck-and-psych-yaml-parsers-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the worker with the command

`rake jobs:work`

on your heroku rails console.